# how to correctly load webview based on sample of creating swipe view

Tags: android

I am new and learning to create a webview by selecting a tab, based on google's sample at http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html.

I created a class for webview fragment:

```
public static class WebViewFragment<rootView> extends Fragment {    
    WebView rootView;
    public WebView onCreate(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_webview_1, container,false);
        rootView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        rootView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

However, it runs without error but the webview interface never shows up.  Appreciate if you can provide any clues.

Answer (score 0):

Above method is actually not called by Android. It is a simple `onCreate` overloaded method.
Change that method to:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // would be safe to check class
    rootView = (WebView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_webview_1, container,false);
    rootView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    rootView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: "...case 1:
                 return new WebViewFragment(); ..."  calls     

public static class WebViewFragment extends Fragment {
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            WebView rootView = (WebView) inflater.inflate(R.id.webView1, container, false);
            rootView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
         rootView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
            return rootView;
        }
    }

But shows failed. :(

Comment: You need to provide more details in your initial question. How are you managing the activities? How do you load them? The question so far is not concise-enough.